# What posts the WM_QUIT message?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have just started on NeHe's OpenGl tutorials and I have written all the code from the first tutorial. 
The program didn't run how i wanted it to run so i started to debug it and found out that a WM_QUIT message was posted somewhere.

I didn't post it anywhere exept from "case close:"(which never happens, I don't get that far).

So i just wondered, what could possibly post a WM_QUIT message. I am not that familiar with c++, but i have done a lot of java before.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my bad English.

Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>
#include <glaux.h>
#include <iostream>

 // Window/Rendering vars
 HGLRC     hRC       = NULL; // Handle to the rendering context
 HDC       hDC       = NULL; // Handle to Device context    
 HWND      hWnd      = NULL; // Handle to the Window
 HINSTANCE hInstance = NULL; // Handle to a instance of the application

 bool active     = true; // Is window active
 bool fullscreen = true; // Is window fullscreen



 bool keys[256]; // Array for keypresses

 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM); // Declaration of the window      procedure


 GLvoid ResizeGLScene(GLsizei width, GLsizei height) //resize and initialize GL window 
{
if(height == 0)
{
    height = 1;
}

glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // Code after this will affect the projection matrix
glLoadIdentity();            // Reset the current matrix(projection)

gluPerspective(45.0f, width/height, 0.1f, 100.0f); // setting the perspective and calculating aspect ratio

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // Code after this will affect the modelview matrix
glLoadIdentity();           // Reset the current matrix(modelview)
 }

 int InitGL(GLvoid)  //Setup and initialize openGL
 {
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); //Set shademodel to smooth shading

glClearColor(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f); //set the screen default color rgb

glClearDepth(1.0f);      // set default depth to 1 and setup    
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enables depth test
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);  // indicates the type of depth test

glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  // nicest perspective calculations

return true;
}

int DrawGLScene(GLvoid)         //DRAWING
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // set the screen to the clear  color and clears the depth buffer

glLoadIdentity();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(100, 200);

glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(200, 200);

glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(200, 100);

glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(100, 100);

glEnd();

return true;
}

 GLvoid KillGLWindow(GLvoid)
 {
if(fullscreen)  // is fuulscreen active
{
    ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0);  // use default displaysetting(no fullscreen)
    ShowCursor(true);  
}

if(hRC)  // is a rendering context present?
{
    if(!wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL))  // can device context and rendering context be released?
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Couldn't Release DC And RC", "Shutdown Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }

    if(!wglDeleteContext(hRC)) // can rendering context be deleted
    {


        MessageBox(NULL, "Couldn't Release DC And RC", "Shutdown Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);MessageBox(NULL, "Couldn't Delete Rendering Context", "Shutdown Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }

    hRC = NULL;
}

if(hDC && !ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC))  // Can device context be released
{

        MessageBox(NULL, "Couldn't Release Device Context", "Shutdown Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

if(hWnd && !DestroyWindow(hWnd))  // can window be destroyed
{

        MessageBox(NULL, "Couldn't destroy window handle", "Shutdown Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

        hWnd = NULL;
}

if(!UnregisterClass("OpenGL", hInstance))
{

        MessageBox(NULL, "Couldn't Unregister Class", "Shutdown Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        hInstance = NULL;
}
}

BOOL CreateGLWindow(char* title, int width, int height, int bits, bool fullscreenflag)
{
GLuint PixelFormat;

WNDCLASS wc;

DWORD dwExStyle; //Window Extended Style
DWORD dwStyle;   //Window Style

RECT WindowRect;
WindowRect.left = 0;
WindowRect.right = width;
WindowRect.top = 0;
WindowRect.bottom = height;

fullscreen = fullscreenflag;

hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = "OpenGL";

if(!RegisterClass(&wc))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Couldn't Register The Window Class", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;
}

if(fullscreen)
{
    DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;           //Device Mode
    memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));
    dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);
    dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = width;
    dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = height;
    dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = bits;
    dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

    if(ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN) != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
    {
        if(MessageBox(NULL, "Fullscreen mode not supported by Graphics Card. Do you want to use windowed mode?", "OpenGL", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION) == IDYES)
        {
            fullscreen = false;
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Program is closing.", "CLOSING", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
            return false;
        }

    }

}

if(fullscreen)
{
    dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
    dwStyle = WS_POPUP;
    ShowCursor(false);
}
else
{
    dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
    dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
}

AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowRect, dwStyle, false, dwExStyle);

if(!(hWnd = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle,
                        "OpenGL",
                        title,
                        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS |
                        WS_CLIPCHILDREN |
                        dwStyle,
                        0, 0,
                        WindowRect.right - WindowRect.left,
                        WindowRect.bottom - WindowRect.top,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        hInstance,
                        NULL)))
{
    KillGLWindow();
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window creation error", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;
}

static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = 
{
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
    1,
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
    PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |
    PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
    bits,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    16,
    0,
    0,
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
    0, 
    0, 0, 0

};

if(!(hDC = GetDC(hWnd)))
{
    KillGLWindow();
    MessageBox(NULL, "Can't create a Gl Device Context.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;
}

if(!(PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd)))
{
    KillGLWindow();
    MessageBox(NULL, "Couldn't find the rigth pixelformat", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;
}

if(!SetPixelFormat(hDC, PixelFormat, &pfd))
{
    KillGLWindow();
    MessageBox(NULL, "Couldn't set pixelformat", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;
}

if(!(hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC)))
{
    KillGLWindow();
    MessageBox(NULL, "Can't create a Gl rendering Context.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;
}

if(!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC))
{
    KillGLWindow();
    MessageBox(NULL, "Can't activate a Gl rendering Context.", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;
}

ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
SetFocus(hWnd);
ResizeGLScene(width, height);

if(!InitGL())
{
    KillGLWindow();
    MessageBox(NULL, "GL Initialization Failed", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;
}

return true;
} 


 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 {
switch(uMsg)
{
case WM_ACTIVATE:
    {
        if(!HIWORD(wParam))
        {
            active = true;
        }
        else
        {
            active = false;
        }

        return 0;
    }

case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
    {
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case SC_SCREENSAVE:
        case SC_MONITORPOWER:
        return 0;

        }
        break;
    }

case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        std::cout << "Close" << std::endl;
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        keys[wParam] = true;
        return 0;
    }

case WM_KEYUP:
    {
        keys[wParam] = false;
        return 0;
    }

case WM_SIZE:
    {
        ResizeGLScene(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
        return 0;
    }
}

return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

 int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
 {
MSG msg;
bool done = false;

if(MessageBox(NULL, "Run application in fullscreen mode?", "Initate Fullscreen", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDNO)
{
    fullscreen = false;
}

if(!CreateGLWindow("NeHe's OpenGl Framework", 800, 600, 16, fullscreen))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "framwork failed", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return 0;
}

while(!done)
{
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if(msg.message = WM_QUIT)
        {
            std::cout << "EXIT" << std::endl;
            done = false;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
            std::cout << "Translate and Dispatch Msg" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(active)
        {
            if(keys[VK_ESCAPE])
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                DrawGLScene();
                SwapBuffers(hDC);
            }
        }
        if(keys[VK_F1])
        {
            keys[VK_F1] = false;
            KillGLWindow();
            fullscreen =! fullscreen;

            if(!CreateGLWindow("NeHe's OpenGL Framework", 800, 600, 16, fullscreen))
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

KillGLWindow();
return (msg.wParam);
}
```

Comment: Typically `PostQuitMessage()`, usually called when `WM_DESTROY` comes along.

Comment: Perhaps a windows tag is appropriate. Don't see what the actual question has to do with opengl.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Without seeing the code, this is a guessing game.

Comment: This line: `if(msg.message = WM_QUIT)` should be `==`; which is probably what's terminating your application at the very start.

Comment: @Petesh: You should make that an answer

Comment: The ode you posted isn't particularly short (the first S in SSCCE). For example, the `DrawGLScene` function doesn't seem relevant and could probably have been deleted from the code without affecting the underlying problem. Also, you need to turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of this program the thing that's setting the message to `WM_QUIT` is this:

```
if(msg.message = WM_QUIT)
```

You've accidentally set the message to `WM_QUIT` instead of testing for the value by using `==`, and because the result of the operation is a non-zero value it always evaluates the true section. In other words it terminates as soon as it receives even a single message rather than pumping the message loop.

If you change the line to:

```
if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
```

Then it tests, instead of assigning the value, and should work correctly.

In general, compiling with full warnings will point this one out.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632641(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **WM_QUIT message**
>   Indicates a request to terminate an application, and ***is generated when the application calls the PostQuitMessage function***. This message causes the GetMessage function to return zero.

Comment: Then what calls the PostQuitMessage? I dont do it in the code.

Comment: @user2851949: If you're following the first legacy tutorial, then [you wrote `PostQuitMessage()` when handling `WM_CLOSE`](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_\(win32\)/13001/).

Comment: Yeah, but why is WM_CLOSE called? I don't see where it is called.

Comment: @user2851949: Typically `WM_CLOSE` is called when the user hits the red X to close the window. If the window is closed, it's sent the `WM_CLOSE` message.

Comment: But i don't ever get so far. i start the program, get a messagebox that asks if i want fullscreen i answer that and then it exits.

Comment: @user2851949: Then that's a different issue, and it's time you learn to use your debugger to step through your program, line by line while it's executing.

Comment: I have done that but, i just can't figure out what calls the quitmessage, but thanks anyways.